# Qt QObject dynamic array

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a different way to create a dynamic array of QObject? The following code would not compile:

```
QStringList labels = defaultScene->getLabels();
QAction* traceActions = new QAction[labels.size()];
```

The error is:

C2512: 'QAction' : no appropriate default constructor available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this because QAction doesn't have a default constructor.

You could create an array of pointers to QAction and then instantiate each QAction on it's own.

Something roughly like:

```
QAction** actions = new (QAction*)[labels.size()];
for(size_t i = 0; i<labels.size(); ++i)
{
  actions[i] = new QAction(constructor params ...);
}
```

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon: You asked, in a comment on a now deleted answer, *"Is there a particular advantage in using that [QValueVector] instead of something simple?"* -- Keeping in mind that you have to make sure you call delete on all those pointers, and the fact that the code in this answer is not exception safe, do you not clearly see the advantage of using a container like `QValueVector`?  Exception safety, little to no risk of memory leaks, code that's not ugly.  Those seem like pretty big advantages to me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: personally I'd prefer to use the standard library equivalents to provide for exception safety and lifetime control. std::vector<QAction> should do the trick.